# Excluding images S2 that are not complete in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel

I work in a place where need to use several images S2, I have some images like a triangle, I know it's because of the orbit but how can I exclude them from my collection?

This is a example ID: COPERNICUS/S2/20180107T153609_20180107T153816_T17MNS
[image]

Answer (score 1):

`filterMedatada` is the function you need. Use `.filterMetadata('SENSING_ORBIT_NUMBER','equals', x)` where `x` is the orbit number you want to preserve. Check image metadata if you don't know the orbit number

Reproducible example counting the number of images in a zone:

```
var geometry = 
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-71.28142150268555, -29.932217626930008],
          [-71.28142150268555, -29.9905162362859],
          [-71.10461028442383, -29.9905162362859],
          [-71.10461028442383, -29.932217626930008]]], null, false);

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
                  .filterDate('2022-05-01', '2022-06-10').
                  filterBounds(geometry);

var visualization = {
  min: 0,
  max: 20,
};

Map.setCenter(-71.2761, -29.9256, 12);

var c1 = dataset.count()

var c2 = dataset.filterMetadata('SENSING_ORBIT_NUMBER','equals', 96).count()

Map.addLayer(c1, visualization, 'no filtered');
Map.addLayer(c2, visualization, 'filtered');
```

Comment: Thanks for you help but yet I had continued the same problem the collection still including the cuting of images. I find a easier solution. I drawn 4 points in the study area and have obtained just the images I need.